# How can an asynchronous task be used to modify data on-the-fly?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task

I am trying to slowly write text to the screen. If the spacebar is held down, the text appears faster. If it is released again, it goes back to the same speed.

```
//Displays text at a certain speed
public async void DisplayText(string text, Speed speed = Speed.medium, ConsoleColor color = ConsoleColor.White, bool newLine = false)
{
    completed = false;

    //Defines color and speed
    Console.ForegroundColor = color;
    scrollSpeed = DefineSpeed(speed);

    var keyCheck = Task.Run(() => CheckSpeedUp());

    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        //If the asynchronous background method has detected the spacebar is pressed... 
        //Speed the text up, otherwise put it back to default.
        if (speedUp)
            scrollSpeed = 15;
        else
            scrollSpeed = 200;

        Console.Write(c);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(scrollSpeed);
    }

    //Display has finished
    completed = true;

    //If there is a new line, write it
    if (newLine)
        Console.WriteLine();

    //Set the text color back to white
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
}
```

Doing this without another thread resulted in a lot of delay between when the text would start speeding up and when it would slow down.
I tried to resolve this by creating a task that would take care of it on its own thread. That way, the main code only has to worry about the boolean "speedUp".

```
//Asynchronous task to check if the spacebar is pressed and set the speedUp bool
private async Task CheckSpeedUp()
{
    while(!completed)
    {
        if (Program.IsKeyDown(ConsoleKey.Spacebar))
        {
            speedUp = true;
        }
        else
        {
            speedUp = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that this system would speed up the rate at which the foreach loop displays its text, and slow it down again when the spacebar is released.

However, about 500 milliseconds after the spacebar is pressed (or even tapped) the text will speed up until the code exits without any alteration.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting something together quick in an winforms app with a button `button1` and a timer `timer1`, this seems to work. I did have to set the `KeyPreview` property of the form to `true`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int _position = 0;
    string _text = string.Empty;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!timer1.Enabled)
            DisplayText(@"//Displays text at a certain speed test...");
    }

    //Displays text at a certain speed
    public void DisplayText(string text, int speed = 200, Color color = default(Color), bool newLine = false)
    {
        _position = 0;
        _text = text;
        timer1.Interval = speed;

        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_position < _text.Length)
            Debug.Write(_text[_position]);
        else
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        _position++;
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
            timer1.Interval = 15;
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = 200;
    }
}
```

I know this is slightly different than what you were doing, but I hope you can get the gist.  I removed all of the the code that didn't have to do with the text writing (like changing the color of the text) for clarity.